# Upgrade all npm packages in React Native

Tags: react-native, npm-update

I want to upgrade all npm packages to latest stable versions of my react native application. Is there any standard procedure to do that ? Good to mention that I have both android and ios users, so I cannot afford any OS related conflicts.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a direct easy way, but it would be better to check each package on its own in npmjs.org, updating them in package.json manually then running npm install, so you avoid huge conflicts.

Comment: You can check outdated npm by `npm outdated` command in project path which display current,required and new versions of npm